# Lambda expression to replace if statement

Tags: c#, quartz

I would like to remove the if statement with a lambda expression to avoid duplication

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationSettings.Hour.ToString()))
{
       service.ScheduleQuartzJob(q =>
       q.WithJob(() =>
       JobBuilder.Create<ServiceJob>().Build())
       .AddTrigger(() => TriggerBuilder.Create()
       .WithCronSchedule(ConfigurationSettings.RunAtSchedule)
       .Build()));
}
else
{
       service.ScheduleQuartzJob(q =>
       q.WithJob(() =>
       JobBuilder.Create<ServiceJob>().Build())
       .AddTrigger(() => TriggerBuilder.Create()
       .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder
       .DailyAtHourAndMinute(ConfigurationSettings.Hour,
       ConfigurationSettings.RunAtMinute))
       .Build()));
}
```

How can I refactor this to replace the if statement using a lambda?

Many thanks

Garry

Comment: Do you mean you want to pass a lambda into the method that this is declared in to replace thhe `.AddTrigger( .... )` part?

Comment: Yes after the AddTrigger(() => TriggerBuilder.Create() part. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear what you mean by replacing it with a lambda. But I think this may be *close* to what you are after:

```cs
var builder = TriggerBuilder.Create();
var schedule = string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationSettings.Hour.ToString()) 
    ? builder.WithCronSchedule(ConfigurationSettings.RunAtSchedule)
    : builder.WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.DailyAtHourAndMinute(ConfigurationSettings.Hour, ConfigurationSettings.RunAtMinute));

service.ScheduleQuartzJob(
  q => q.WithJob(
    () => JobBuilder.Create<ServiceJob>().Build())
                    .AddTrigger(() => schedule.Build())
  ) 
);
```

I'm not familiar with Quartz, but I *assume* the above should work. If you need to pass it all within the lambda, you could do this instead:

```cs
service.ScheduleQuartzJob(
  q => q.WithJob(
    () => JobBuilder.Create<ServiceJob>().Build())
                    .AddTrigger(
                          () => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationSettings.Hour.ToString()) 
                              ? TriggerBuilder.Create().WithCronSchedule(ConfigurationSettings.RunAtSchedule)
                              : TriggerBuilder.Create().WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.DailyAtHourAndMinute(ConfigurationSettings.Hour, ConfigurationSettings.RunAtMinute))
                            ).Build()
             )
      ) 
);
```

Note: I *think* I matched all the closing parenthesis, but it's possible I missed one as I typed this on mobile.

Comment: Note: I typed this on my mobile phone. It's possible that it's missing a closing parenthesis. To reviewers: the formatting looks semi-ok on mobile, I would be happy with an edit that tweaks the appearance